# Fishing mini game automatically restarting (Unity, C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a fishing mini-game as part of my project. The rules are that when the player is in a certain location (near water) they can press E to cast their line and then wait a random length of time before a fish bites. They then have to press E again within a short time frame in order to catch the fish. Finally, they are given the choice to keep the fish or throw it back in the water. If they press E again within a larger time frame they can keep it if they wait too long, it gets thrown back in.

This whole process does work, however, the issue comes across when the sequence has finished or been cancelled due to the player failing the mini-game.

As this is part of a much larger project, I'm using a big if statement to check certain conditions when the player presses E. One of these conditions are what's required to go fishing. When the condition is met, a bool is set to true to notify another script that I want to run the "Fishing" method.

From what I can tell, despite this code being told to only run under this condition, and me explicitly writing "usingRod = false" whenever the game ends or is cancelled, the mini game loops again, leaving the player stuck in an endless game of fishing.

I understand that this is probably not the most efficient way of detecting input and running a minigame but it's worked fine so far so haven't really needed to change anything.

Here's the fishing method:

```
public void Fishing()
{
    if (playerController.usingRod)
    {
        playerController.DisablePlayerInput();

        if (fishStage == 0)
        {
            playerAnimator.SetTrigger("fishing_cast");

            Debug.Log("waiting for bite");

            if (!generated)
            {
                random = Random.Range(randomWaitTime.x, randomWaitTime.y);
                generated = true;
            }

            timer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (timer >= random)
            {
                Debug.Log("Bite");
                playerAnimator.SetTrigger("fishing_bite");
                timer = 0;
                generated = false;
                fishStage = 1;
            }
            else if (timer < random && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                Debug.Log("reel too early");
                playerAnimator.SetTrigger("fishing_fail");

                CancelInteraction();
            }
        }
        else if (fishStage == 1)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (timer < 1f && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                playerAnimator.SetInteger("fishing_randomIndex", Random.Range(1, 5));
                Debug.Log("caught");
                timer = 0;
                fishStage = 2;
            }
            else if (timer > 1f && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                playerAnimator.SetTrigger("fishing_fail");
                CancelInteraction();

            }
            else if (timer > 2f)
            {
                playerAnimator.SetTrigger("fishing_fail");
                CancelInteraction();

            }
        }
        else if (fishStage == 2)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (timer <= 5f && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                playerAnimator.SetTrigger("fishing_keep");
                CancelInteraction();

            }
            else if (timer >= 5f)
            {
                playerAnimator.SetTrigger("fishing_throw");
                CancelInteraction();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the condition to set usingRod to true in the large if statement being called in Update()

(This is nested within an Input.GetKeyDown() check)

```
if (currentInventoryIndex == 2 && interactionsManager.interaction.requiredTool == 2)
{
        usingRod = true;

}
```

Here is the if statement that runs the interaction code if usingRod = true

```
private void Update()
{
    if (interaction != null)
    {
        if (interaction.GetInteractable())
        {
            canInteract = true;
        }
        else
        {
            canInteract = false;
        }

        if (!interaction.GetComplete() && !interaction.GetCancelled())
        {
            if (interaction.interactionName == "Squirrel")
            {
                indivInteractions.Squirrel();
            }
            else if (interaction.interactionName == "Fetch")
            {
                indivInteractions.Fetch();

            }
            else if (interaction.interactionName == "BlueJay")
            {
                indivInteractions.BlueJay();
            }
            else if (interaction.interactionName == "Deer")
            {
                indivInteractions.Deer();
            }

            else if (playerController.usingAxe)
            {
                if (playerController.currentInventoryIndex == 1)
                {
                    if (interaction.interactionName == "TreeChop1")
                    {
                        indivInteractions.Chop();
                    }

                    if (interaction.interactionName == "CampWood")
                    {
                        indivInteractions.CampsiteChop();
                    }

                    if (interaction.interactionName == "FallenTree")
                    {
                        indivInteractions.FallenBridge();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (playerController.usingRod)
            {
                if (playerController.currentInventoryIndex == 2)
                {
                    if (interaction.interactionName == "Fishing")
                    {
                        indivInteractions.Fishing();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate this is a long post however I've been stuck on this for a while now and due to covid, I'm struggling to contact my peers to get their help too!

Many thanks for any feedback, and if there's any more information required let me know!
Jamie

Comment: Have you considered debugging to see how the code works when it loops (i.e. stepping through the if-statements, inspecting variables along the way)? This should also tell you why it makes the decision to loop at all.

Comment: I must admit I'm not too knowledgable on how to use the debugging stuff in Visual studio but I have been watching variables turn on and off as required in the inspector in unity. I can see that usingRod does remain true. Normally if something is keeping it true, you are unable to turn it off manually but I am able to in my case which is confusing me further haah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i see in first approach is:

At the end or beginning of processus, i dont see the fact to reset at 0 the value timer

what i could suggest is to cut each state in method... so following the state of game you execute the method corresponding... its better to see and debug easily your logic of game...

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, would you mind elaborating though as I'm not sure what you mean :)

Comment: i have no idea how you call the fishing method..could you show your update(). So i dont know if you reset the variable timer

Comment: Hello, I've updated the post. The only reason I didn't show in the first place was because there was lots of irrelevent code

Comment: when do you do:  playerController.usingRod = false;   i dont see it in your loop

Comment: ah apologies again, it's in the CancelInteraction() method

Comment: Yeah I  do. An interesting development though is that the code works as intended if the player does not press any button

Comment: so its too difficult to debug without complete code..i suggest you to put somewhere a functional package....

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help so far! I'm not sure what you mean but you've at least helped me getting the ball rolling!

Comment: dont forget even the solution is not in view to upvote for the effort